# jquery- sum of dynamic created column

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with dynamic created rows. Now I need to calculate sum of one column of it. This code working only for 1st row:

```
$('.class').each(function() {
     sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
     sum = sum.toFixed(2);
});
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
var sum = 0;
$.each($('.class').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get(), function (i, v) { sum += v; });
sum = sum.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: It works but I must change 'sum += v' to 'sum += parseFloat(v)' because without it my sum looks like this : 1234.56.567.89. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your calculation code inside a function like below,

```
function calculateTotal () {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.class').each(function() {
     sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
     sum = sum.toFixed(2);
  });
  return sum;
}
```

Now call `calculateTotal()` whenever you want to get the updated value.

Comment: My code is a part of function execute when 'keypress' in inputs.

Comment: @user1972252 Did you mention that in your question?

Comment: @user1972252 Move that part of code in a function like above and call it from there.

Comment: Sorry, I move it and I have still the same effect- after adding new row function not working.

Comment: @user1972252 You have to call this function to get the updated value. The calculated value will be based on what was there at that point of time.